# ios sdk swift : Show in-app app update/install prompt

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, app-store

Does anyone know what Api are used to achieve this. In the below image we a prompt appears that allow us to install/update another app.
This seems to be native and it has same behavior as the the in app purchase

[image]

Comment: You should look into StoreKit https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skoverlay

Answer (score 0):

You want to use StoreKit, specifically `SKOverlay`

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skoverlay)

In UIKit in the  UIViewController where you want to show it you can use the following code:

```swift
func displayOverlay() {
    guard let scene = view.window?.windowScene else { return }

    let config = SKOverlay.AppConfiguration(
        appIdentifier: "The iTunes identifier of another app.", 
        position: .bottom
    )
    let overlay = SKOverlay(configuration: config)
    overlay.present(in: scene)
}
```

In SwiftUI you can use it in the following way:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var presentingAppStoreOverlay = false
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            presentingAppStoreOverlay.toggle()
        } label: {
            Text("Show SKOverlay")
        }
        .appStoreOverlay(isPresented: $presentingAppStoreOverlay) {
            SKOverlay.AppConfiguration(
                appIdentifier: "The iTunes identifier of another app.",
                position: .bottom
            )
        }
    }
}
```